# How can I return two variables in Odoo?

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-view

I need check two conditions and get the details print on the report. But the problem is I can't able to return the two variables. I'll submit the code and mention more below.

class TaxDetailReport(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'tax.detail.report'

```
start_date = fields.Datetime(required=True)
end_date = fields.Datetime(required=True)
vat_oman_id = fields.Many2one('vat.oman.import', string="VAT Oman ID")

@api.multi
def generate_report(self):
    for file in self:
        if file.start_date and file.end_date:
            record_ids = self.env['vat.oman.import'].search([('date', '>=', self.start_date),
                                                             ('date', '<=', self.end_date),
                                                             ('account_tax_id.type_tax_use', '=', 'sale')
                                                             ])
            purchase_ids = self.env['vat.oman.import'].search([('date', '>=', self.start_date),
                                                             ('date', '<=', self.end_date),
                                                             ('account_tax_id.type_tax_use', '=', 'purchase')
                                                             ])
        else:
            raise UserError("Record does not exist")

        result['file'] = {'print': [(record_ids,purchase_ids)]}
    return self.env["report"].get_action(result, 'kg_oman_vat.report_tax_details')
```

I need to return those `product_ids` and `record_ids` . `generate_report` is the button which is in the wizard.

```
class VATOmanImport(models.Model):
    _name = 'vat.oman.import'
    _rec_name = 'partner_id'
    _description = 'Oman VAT Import'

    partner_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string="Name", required=True)
    invoice_desc = fields.Char(string="Description", help="Invoice Description")
    date = fields.Date(string="Date")
    account_tax_id = fields.Many2one('account.tax', string="Tax Type")
    state_id = fields.Many2one('res.country.state', string="State", required=True,
                               domain="[('country_id', '=','Oman')]")
    invoice_amount = fields.Float(string="Invoice Amount", required=True)
    tax_amount = fields.Float(string="Total Tax", compute='_compute_tax_amount')
    company_id = fields.Many2one('res.company', string='Company', index=True,
                                 default=lambda self: self.env.user.company_id)
```

Just mentioned above is the main class, and need to get the details from here.

Is there is any solutions ? Hope somebody will help.

Comment: Hi pablo, when did you become python developer from the drug mafia? Lolz

Comment: I have not worked with odoo yet, maybe try returning a tuple or list object from the method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understood is that you want to show this data on your report.

So you need to understand something in report that could help you.

You can call method in `t-esc` or `t-set` like in python code.

So lets say I want to show a complicated value in my report so what I do is this:

I create a method that just compute and return the value that I want to print.

```py
  @api.multi
  def calculate_complicated_value(self):
       .....
       .....
       .....
       return value
```

And In my template I can call this method and print the `value`

```xml
  <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="rec">

      <!-- I prefer always to save it in a variable first -->
      <t t-set='result'  t-value='rec.calculate_complicated_value()'/>
      <!-- And here I can loop on my result or handle anything the method call returns -->
```

I prefer this technique better than passing data on my `get_action` call like Odoo developer do in there standard modules.

You can see how you can pass data to your report template and show them you need to create extra `AbstractModel` and the name must start with `report.`

in your case you may try this solution:

```py
     _name = 'tax.detail.report'

     @api.multi
     def generate_report(self):
                                 # in report docs = self
     return return self.env["report"].get_action(self, 'kg_oman_vat.report_tax_details')


     @api.multi
     def compute_purschaces(self):
            # i don't think you need to loop here because you are calling
            # the method with one record in the report
            # you can refactor it later if you want
            for file in self:
                if file.start_date and file.end_date:
                    record_ids = self.env['vat.oman.import'].search([('date', '>=', self.start_date),
                                                                     ('date', '<=', self.end_date),
                                                                     ('account_tax_id.type_tax_use', '=', 'sale')
                                                                     ])
                    purchase_ids = self.env['vat.oman.import'].search([('date', '>=', self.start_date),
                                                                     ('date', '<=', self.end_date),
                                                                     ('account_tax_id.type_tax_use', '=', 'purchase')
                                                                     ])
                    return {'record_ids': record_ids, 'purchase_ids': purchase_ids}
                else:
                    # raising error from report calls is not a good thing the message will look ugly ^^
                    # try to add this check in generate_report so the message look nice for your user
                    raise UserError("Record does not exist")
            return False
```

In your template

```xml
           <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="rec">

               <t t-set="result" t-value="rec.compute_purschaces()"/>

               <!-- now if you want to show record_ids in table or something you can access like this result['record_ids'] -->
               <t t-foreach="result['record_ids']" t-as="record">
                    ........
                    .......
```

And in you report action The model should be: `'tax.detail.report'`

```xml
  <report
    ...
    ...
    model="tax.detail.report"
   .....
   .....
   ./>
```

This is how I do it it's easer than passing the extra parameter `data` to the `get_action` call and creating that special `AbstractModel`
to treat the data before it goes the template to make sure that `docs` are set correctly and so on.
Hope you get the idea

Answer (score 1):

I could not understand your question very well, but if you want return 2 parameters in one function you have 2 choice.

1.

```
def function_name():
  a=1
  b=2
  return a,b
```

2.

```
def function_name():
      a=1
      b=2
      return {a':a,'b':b}
```

Comment: No man, It's not working. I need to return `record_ids` and `purchase_ids` in `return` . That's what I'm asking man.